# Как рядом с ползунком jQuery UI Slider поместить поле со значением ползунка?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript

Делаю ползунок, изменяющий значения. Использую jQuery UI Slider.
Как рядом с ползунком поместить поле для вывода значения? Например,
калькулятор на http://okonka.com/

Как вывести значение, понятно. Нужно именно поле, которое будет передвигаться
вместе с ползунком и выводить значение.

Проблема в том, что для вставки слайдера я вставляю див, а внутренности дива скрипт сам дописывает.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[JQuery UI Slider # Change Event](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change)

UPD

Даже лучше [JQuery UI Slider # Slide Event](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide)

Вся функциональность плагина есть на сайте, как документация, так и всевозможные живые примеры. И я не вижу там из коробки того, что бы Вам было нужно. К тому же я не понимаю, в чем такая сложность написать пару строк кода?

```
[css]
.view{
    position:relative;
}

[HTML]
<div class="default">
    <div class="view"></div>
    <div class="slider"></div>
</div>

[Java Script]
$( ".slider" ).slider({
    value: 50,
    slide: function( event, ui ){
        var val = ui.value,
            sliderWidth = $( ".slider" ).width();
        $(".view").html(val).css("left",(sliderWidth*val)/100+"px");

    }
});
```

Comment: И куда выводится значение? Проблема не в том, как вывести, а в том, как добавить див в ползунок, в котором будет выводиться. Чтобы див ездил за ползунком, как на примере.

Comment: Свойства position:relative по отношению к этому div ползунка + значение top и left математически высчитать, как вариант.

Comment: Наверное, есть какое-то более стандартное решение, исходя из функционала плагина.

Comment: @Виктор Павлов, вот Вам [еще примеры со stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582564/jquery-ui-slider-how-to-make-a-box-follow-the-handler), если надо.